# Errores de MySql y no se como solucionarlos

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Estoy haciendo un trabajo práctico y me dieron un archivo .sql con una base de datos y algunos datos. La idea es ejecutar el script y permitir que todo se cargue en mi mysql pero me tira algunos errores el script. (desde donde tengo que entregar el trabajo práctico dicen que a ellos no les genera ningún problema y no me ayudan que con mas que eso, a mi me pasa en 2 pcs distintas lo mismo).
Adjunto archivo sql con los datos(lo subo a mega porque es muy largo):
[Enlace a archivo .sql por mega](https://mega.nz/#!nSYFUAoT!dntFnTTWSe2LBbvlz0klweFNCiw4IpUhDDk_-HyQhD4)
Y aquí adjunto los errores que me salen.

> ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xC3\xA1n Na...' for
>   column 'nombre' at row 23
>
> ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xC3\xB3n' for column
>   'nombre' at row 1
>
> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`competencias`.`pelicula`, CONSTRAINT
>   `pelicula_genero` FOREIGN KEY (`genero_id`) REFERENCES `genero`
>   (`id`))
>
> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`competencias`.`actor_pelicula`, CONSTRAINT
>   `ap_actor_id` FOREIGN KEY (`actor_id`) REFERENCES `actor` (`id`))
>
> ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xC3\xA8s Ja...' for
>   column 'nombre' at row 5
>
> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`competencias`.`director_pelicula`, CONSTRAINT
>   `director_id` FOREIGN KEY (`director_id`) REFERENCES `director`
>   (`id`))

Estuve leyendo algo en internet y dice que los errores 1366 son porque no puede cargar los bytes y debo pasar mi base de datos a utf8 especial que tiene mysql y así funcionaria...
Ejecuté algunos comandos alter table alter database que modificaban la codificación pero no se soluciono.
Y supongo que los errores 1452 son generados porque no se pudo escribir algo cuando da los errores 1366.

Poseo la versión 8.0.15 MySQL Community Server.
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Nos ayudaría mucho para poder auxiliarte que nos compartas por ejemplo la estructura de tus tablas así como unos datos de ejemplo de lo que tratas de almacenar para poder identificar mas rápido que esta ocurriendo, *considera no colocar toda tu bd si es muy extensa y solo una muestra representativa*

Comment: @Aprendiz creo que ni llego a ese punto. no puede cargar su archivo de base de datos, y probablemente sea un problema de codificacion. Te recomiendo que crees una base nueva con la codificacion requerida y hagas la importacion sobre ella.

Comment: Ese script que pasé se encarga de hacer todo, crear la base de datos y crear las tablas, no hay mas nada que eso...por eso se me complica el tema de la codificación porque intenté hacer un alter table y no me anduvo así, capaz hay que hacer algo más, o mas completo que lo que hice.

Comment: Incluye en tu pregunta las lineas del script que hacen eso entonces

Comment: Es que no se cuales son, si lo supiera estaría corrigiéndolas. El script es tal cual así me lo dieron y me genera problemas en mi mysql, estoy seguro que es por la codificación utf8 pero no se como cambiarla totalmente.

Comment: seguro son las primeras. analiza que hace cada linea del script y ponlas aca. Yo lo siento, pero no voy a abrir un archivo externo e iria contra las politicas del sitio ya que toda la informacion debe estar en la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Para resolverlo en mi script donde decia charset estaba en latin1 y lo cambie por utf8mb4 en cada parte donde lo nombraba y anduvo sin errores!

Comment: Explica como hiciste esto, y donde tuviste que cambiar para que la respuesta sea valida. Si no, solo parece un comentario.

Comment: Está explicado, en el script en cada parte donde decia charset (usando el buscador del notepad por ejemplo) decia latin1, bueno ahi hay que poner utf8mb4 y listo, el script es larguisimo por eso no soy mas especifico que buscarlo.